# linear decision boundaries of using the Euclidean distance?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, euclidean

How does Euclidean-norm in K-means cause it to have linear decision boundaries?
The Euclidean-norm is a non-linear measure between two points, then how does it make the boundaries till linear?

Answer (score 1):

K-means clustering works by creating a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) that has linear decision boundaries between clusters, as you know. This means that you can draw lines/planes/hyperplanes to classify your data.

In practice, you are actually using the squared euclidean distance because the sum of squares is being minimised by K-means. Because the square root is monotone, this means that the euclidean distance is minimised as well.

Comment: does this have any mathematical explanation? thannk you